# React MUI - is it possible to place a component / div (a chart for example) inside a Table Cell?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React [MUI](https://mui.com), and I'd like to place a component (a chart for example) inside a Table Cell.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can place any node in MUI Table cell like this:

```
<TableCell>
  <div>
   ...
  </div>
</TableCell>
```

I didn't try with charts, but I was able to place barcode, so it should be matter of adjusting and styling.